# How can I change my code in Excel 2003 to allow me to paste to multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Ran in to a little problem. If I try to paste to multiple cells that are in the range in the code below, I get a run time error 13, type mismatch. The cells in the range may have data other than X but I only want the hyperlink to appear if the cell contains X. It works fine if I just type an X in the cell or if I paste to one cell at a time.  I will have times when I want to paste other text to mutiple cells in this range.  Thanks to Remnant for his help on the original code.  This one last hurdle will put me in the clear.  Thx.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rangeLimit As Range

 Set rangeLimit = Range 
("B9:B37,C9:C37,D9:D37,E9:E37,F9:F37,G9:G37,H9:H37,I9:I37,J9:J37,K9:K37,L9:L37,M9:M37")

 If Not Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) Is Nothing Then
     If Target = "x" Or Target = "X" Then
    Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:="", SubAddress:="Exceptions!A1", 
    TextToDisplay:=Target.Value

  End If

 End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification to the original code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rangeLimit As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rangeLimit = Range("B9:B37,C9:C37,D9:D37,E9:E37,F9:F37,G9:G37,H9:H37,I9:I37,J9:J37,K9:K37,L9:L37,M9:M37")

If Not Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cl In Target
        If cl = "x" Or cl = "X" Then
            cl.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cl, Address:="", SubAddress:="Exceptions!A1", TextToDisplay:=cl.Value
        End If
    Next cl
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thanks for your help.  I can now close this project and move on to the next having learned quite a bit.

Comment: @PikeCoAL - please note that in the 'For each' section of my code it is more robust to use Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) as suggested by iDevlop and you may want to update the code accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rangeLimit As Range
    dim c as range
  
    Set rangeLimit = Range("B9:M37")
    If Not Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) Is Nothing Then
       for each c in Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) 
          If c.value = "x" Then
              c.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:="Exceptions!A1", TextToDisplay:=c.Value
          End If
        next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 - please see my comments to OP. I think your check during the for each loop for the intersect is more robust than mine and I have advised OP as such...

Answer (score 1):

When you paste in a range, 'Target' is a set of cells - not just one cell. If you know this code works for one cell, you can loop over all of the cells in the range target, and call the If statement on each of the cells.